# I want to count the duplicate words from uploaded file in php how i can get it

Tags: php, file-handling

I want to count the duplicate words from an uploaded file in PHP, how do I perform this task?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is way too broad and unspecific so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding repeated words in PHP without specifying the word itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035945/finding-repeated-words-in-php-without-specifying-the-word-itself)

Comment: It is not even clear what _kind_ of file. Are we talking about a basic text file (easy) - or maybe more complex stuff, like Word documents or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are working with a text file, this is a relatively simple task:

```php
<?php

// Get the contents of the file
$contents = "Duplicate duplicate duplicate three times three is twenty six thousand three hundred and fifty one. There are fifty nine people in the universe. Times that by nine and divide it by three, then negate a million and you can calculate the IQ of donald trump. This is pure waffle and I can repeat this nine times but shall restrain and instead talk like ollie and use big words and sound very cool. Funny thing is I've typed n instead of and so many times because it's a habit n I like eating rabbit meat as it is very succulent and juicy. Duplicate words shall be found!";
// Split the contents into an array of individual words
$words = explode(' ', $contents);
// Define arrays to track occurrences and duplicates
$occurrences = [];
$duplicates = [];

// Iterate through each word in the sample
foreach ($words as $word) {
    // Convert word to lower case (case-insensitivity)
    $word = strtolower($word);

    // Increment the current occurrence count of current word
    $occurrences[$word] = isset($occurrences[$word]) ? $occurrences[$word] + 1 : 1;

    // If the word has occurred more than once, add it to our duplicates
    // Remove the in_array call if you wish to count each instance of a duplicated word instead of once per duplicate
    if ($occurrences[$word] > 1 && !in_array($word, $duplicates)) {
        $duplicates[] = $word;
    }
}

// Output the duplicates in a comma separated format
echo "Duplicates in file: " . join(", ", $duplicates);
```

Comment: the function didn't work properly it reads a file but not giving duplicate words

Comment: Try calling strtolower on the $word and reassigning $word to that value, like in  my example. The code was untested and I'm not at home to test it so if this doesn't work I've got no idea unfortunately

Comment: @HasSan Anytime man, glad you solved your problem! If my answer has helped you at all and is factually correct I'd be very grateful if you were to mark it as the accepted answer ☺